# Whats the best/most succinct way to pass multiple linked arrays as method parameters?

Tags: .net, c#-3.0

I have a method that I want to pass in a couple of arrays that are linked, ie item 1 in array 1 corresponds to item 1 in array 2.

I can obviously just pass in 2 arrays, like this:

```
meth({"v1", "x1"}, {"v2", "x2"});
```

But was wondering if C#3.0 (not able to use 4.0 here yet) had any "syntactic sugar" options to handle this, eg via anonymous types, dictionaries or something.

For example was trying an array of anonymous types like this:

```
meth({ new { foo = "v1", bar = "v2" }, new { foo = "x1", bar = "x2" }});
```

But thats not valid (and more longwinded)...

Not sure how it could be done in one line with a dictionary, guess it would need to be split into a few lines...

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
d["v1"] = "v2"; d["x1"] = "x2";
```

Thanks in advance for any thoughts/tips, Chris.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use dictionaries?

Comment: If the values belong together, have you considered creating an object that can hold them both, instead of separating them out into distinct array object? Ie. instead of having an array for first names, and one for last names, have you considered creating one array containing person objects, having both a first and a last name property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx)?